# Why I can't manually call `next` on `file` iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, iterator

This is my Python code. If the line has `:` I'm want to skip this line **and the next line**. I'm trying to use `file.next` since `file` is an iterator. Why is it not working?

```
file=open("example.txt","r") //output of ls -R

currentDirectory=""
for line in file:
    if ":" in line:
        currentDirectory=line[:-1]
        file.next() # Error in this line
        continue
    A=line.split()
    print(A)
    print(len(A))
    print('insert into files set name=${name}, inode=${inode}, isDir=${isDir},size=${size}'
    .format(inode=A[0],name=A[9],isDir="d" in A[1],size=A[5]))
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ls-to-sql.py", line 7, in <module>
    file.next()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next
```

I'm sure there are many other ways to implement the same logic. The question is: why this is not working. And if there is another iteration way to solve it.

Comment: I'm already using `continue` I need to skip 2 lines.

Comment: The `next` *method* was renamed to `__next__` in python 3. You should be using the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) *function* to advance iterators.

Comment: To add to what @Aran-Fey said, you should call `next(file)` instead of `file.next()`.